# Token is getting invalidated using nodejs speakeasy library

Tags: node.js

My purpose is to expire a token after 1hr (3600 secs). While trying with nodejs speakeasy the token is getting invalidated much before that. The below logs are for "1, 10 and 60 minutes" and that also getting invalidated muche before the 1 minute. Max of the time I am getting inconsistent results.

Partial code snippet

```
let secret = speakeasy.generateSecret({
length: 10
});
let seconds= 3600; //1Hr

let token = speakeasy.totp({
  secret: secret.base32,
  step: seconds
});

let otp = {
  "secret": secret.base32.toString(),
  "token": token
};

function checkOTP(otp) {
  let verified = speakeasy.totp.verify({
    secret: otp.secret,
    token: otp.token,
    step: seconds
});
return verified;
}
```

Am I doing something wrong? Few console logs from a sample script:

```
For 1 minute - Invalidated before 18secs
[ Fri Dec 08 2017 09:16:18 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time) ](true) 9:16:59 AM
[ Fri Dec 08 2017 09:16:18 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time) ](false) 9:17:00 AM

For 10Mins - Invalidated before 7minutes
[ Fri Dec 08 2017 09:18:28 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time) ](true) 9:19:59 AM
[ Fri Dec 08 2017 09:18:28 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time) ](true) 9:19:59 AM
[ Fri Dec 08 2017 09:18:28 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time) ](true) 9:19:59 AM
[ Fri Dec 08 2017 09:18:28 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time) ](true) 9:19:59 AM
[ Fri Dec 08 2017 09:18:28 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time) ](false) 9:20:00 AM

For 1Hr - Invalidated before 7minutes
[ Fri Dec 08 2017 11:07:01 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time) ](true) 11:56:41 AM
[ Fri Dec 08 2017 11:07:01 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time) ](true) 11:56:43 AM
[ Fri Dec 08 2017 11:07:01 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time) ](false) 12:00:37 PM
```

What is the appropriate way to validate within the above window?

Answer (score 0):

From the readme of speakeasy it looks like your `token` parameters are wrong:

```
var token = speakeasy.totp({
  secret: secret.base32,
  encoding: 'base32',
  time: 1453667708 // You have this as 'step' not 'time' 
});
```

Comment: I tried with your suggestion and have added time: 120 as seconds in totp(..) for a 2min validation from current time, but no results.It fails in next second.